# Laravel cross check query

Tags: php, laravel

I want show my brands page like: `url/discount/{brand-slug}` so far i can get it done by something like:

```
$brandspromotion = Brand::where('slug', $slug)->OfStatus('Active')->firstOrFail();
```

problem occurs when I try to get only products with same `brand_id` which their `id` is saved in 3rd table named `discounts`.

> In the simple words: I want to **get *only discounted products* of each brand**.

## LOGIC

1. Discounts table saves `product_id`
2. Products table saves `brand_id`
3. Brand has to find it's own `id` from `products` through `discounts` table.

## Code

so far I have this code, which is not working :)

```
public function brandspromotions($slug) {
    $promotions = Discount::Valid()->get();
    $grouped = $promotions->map(function ($item, $key) {
      return $item->products->brand_id;
    });
    $brandspromotion = Brand::where('slug', $slug)->OfStatus('Active')
      ->where('id', $grouped)->get();
    return view('front.brandspromotions', compact('brands', 'brandspromotion'));
  }
```

## UPDATE

`product model`

```
public function discount(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Discount::class, 'product_id', 'id');
  }
public function brand(){
     return $this->belongsTo(Brand::class);
  }
```

`brand model`

```
public function products(){
     return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
  }
```

`discount model`

```
public function products(){
     return $this->belongsTo(Product::class, 'product_id', 'id');
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a brand slug and you want to get only products of this brand which have a record in the `discounts` table:

```
Product::has('discount')
    ->whereHas('brand', function($q) use($slug) {
        $q->where('slug', $slug);
    })
    ->get();
```

Where `discount` and `brand` are the relationships defined in the `Product` model.

Comment: i get `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'products.product_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `products` where exists (select * from `discounts` where `products`.`product_id` = `discounts`.`id`) and exists (select * from `brands` where `products`.`brand_id` = `brands`.`id` and `slug` = lenovo3))`

Comment: @mafortis make sure you've defined both relationships correctly.

Comment: @mafortis the `discount` must be defined as `return $this->hasOne(Discount::class);`. If each product can have many dicounts, change `hasOne` to `hasMany`

Comment: How to avoid duplicate product on discounts table while it has valid discount? as i use `hasOne` that's why i'm asking

Comment: @mafortis you should check if it's existing already before adding a new one. You can do this manually or with `unqiue` validation rule.

Comment: if i use unique then i can't add new discount when last one is expired because it says already has this `product_id`, how i check it manually?

Comment: @mafortis `if (Discount::where('product_id', $productId)->count())`